# "Eintrag" and "Beitrag" for describing a blog post

Tags: word-usage

Suppose there is a blog post and at the top there is usually some metadata like:

```
"Entry date: 21.01.2014 12:12" , "Posted by Herr Mustermann".
```

The translation that I got from a native German speaker was following:

```
"Eintrag vom 21.01.2014 12:12", "Beitrag von Herr Mustermann"
```

So it's "Eintrag" in first case and "Beitrag" in the second case but they refer to the same object (blog post).

I wonder if it's possible to use either one "Beitrag" or "Eintrag" in both these lines?

Comment: Note that your translator used the same grammatical construct for both phrases, whereas the English one mixes two styles, i.e. _Published on …_ or _Author: …_ could be used instead. Your translator also avoided all political correctness pitfalls regarding gender by not choosing _Datum: …, Autor: / Autor/-in: / Autor(in): / AutorIn: / Autor_in: / Autor*in: …_ or something like that.

Comment: I want to use the dative for the second bit, so *Beitrag von Herr**n** Mustermann*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Eintrag = entry
>   Beitrag = contribution

Both nouns are related with verbs:

### eintragen

This means to write a new item into a list.

> Wer mit dem Bus zum Treffen fahren will, muss sich in diese Liste eintragen.
>   Who wants to travel with the bus to the meeting has to enter his name in this list.

So an »Eintrag« is an entry in a list or in something that is similar to a list. (i.e. a logfile or a class book)

### beitragen

This means you add your part to something bigger.

> Ich will mit meiner Spende dazu beitragen, dass es anderen besser geht.
>   With my donation I want to make a contribution in order to help others.

So a »Beitrag« is what someone adds. Together with »Beiträge« from others it forms something that is bigger than what one person could have made alone.

Since an entry in a blog is a contribution, you can use both words, and so all of this four possibilities are correct and understandable:

1. "Eintrag vom 21.01.2014 12:12", "Eintrag von Herr Mustermann"
2. "Eintrag vom 21.01.2014 12:12", "Beitrag von Herr Mustermann"
3. "Beitrag vom 21.01.2014 12:12", "Eintrag von Herr Mustermann"
4. "Beitrag vom 21.01.2014 12:12", "Beitrag von Herr Mustermann"

But because the first part (»xxx vom 21.01.2014 12:12«) has the focus on the list-idea, and because the second part (»xxx von Herr Mustermann«) deals more with Mr. Mustermanns contribution, #2 is the choice you should prefer.

Comment: I agree that #2 should be preferred over #3, but something like #4 could even be better, although I would avoid the repetition: _Beitrag von Herr Mustermann vom 21.01.2014 12:12_ or perhaps _geschrieben von Herr Mustermann am 21.01.2014 um 12:12_.

Answer (score 1):

The words are quite similar, but not exchangeble here:

*Eintrag* would be short for *Logbucheintrag* - which a *We**blog***-entry is basically.

*Beitrag* is a post/addendum to a (forum) thread like a comment. It could also be an editorial in a newspaper, in which case the *entry/Eintrag* part would be misplaced. The terminologies overlap here.

*Posted by XXX* should've been translated as *Geschrieben von XXX* or just  *von XXX* instead. This form is pretty common, too.